# Alert Dialog from navigation Drawer item

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-alertdialog

I want to implement an Alert Dialog directly over the item selected in the Navigation Drawer. I have seen examples but none do what I want, all of them create a fragment first and in the fragment create a button that implement the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to create an alert dialog with your needs.
In this link, you can see all of them.

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog? = activity?.let {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
    builder.apply {
        setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    // User clicked OK button
                })
        setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                })
    }
    // Set other dialog properties
    ...

    // Create the AlertDialog
    builder.create()
}
```

Anyway, it's your choice to implement each way.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand where to put this piece of code. In my MainActivity.java,in the method onNavigationItemSelected() i have the following:        if (id == R.id.nav_reset) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new AddCar()).commit();
        }                                                                                                                           I want to replace that part and put the call to the Dialog. When I put your code here, many errors appears.